# Preimage of Intersection of Two Sets = Intersection of Preimage of Each Set : $f^{-1}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, proof-writing

Prove If $f$ is a function , $f^{-1}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$.

Proof attempt
I am guessing here $A$ and $B$ are sets in the range of $f$. Let's assume $x$ belongs to both $A$ and $B$ and $f^{-1}$ exists for both $A$ and $B$.

Then there must exist a $y$ such that $y = f^{-1}(x)$.

Now by our assumptions $x$ is in intersection of $A$ and $B$ and since $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ exist then $f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$ must also exist. Also since $A$ and $B$ exist and are not equal to null set so $A \cap B$ exists and $f^{-1}(A\cap B)$ also must exist and contain our $y$?? Not sure about the ending in this attempt. Any help would be much appreciated.

Sources : ♦ 2nd Ed $\;$  P219 9.60(e) $\;$  *Mathematical Proofs* by Gary Chartrand,
♦ P214 $\;$ Theorem 12.4.#3 $\;$  *Book of Proof* by Richard Hammack,
♦ P257-258 $\;$  Theorem 5.4.2.#2(a) $\;$   *How to Prove It* by D Velleman.

Comment: You should start by taking $y \in f^{-1} (A \cap B)$. In this case, there is some $x \in A \cap B$ such that $y=f(x)$. Now you want to show that $y \in f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$... Don't forget that $f^{-1}(A) = \{ x : f(x) \in A \}$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note that by definition of [inverse image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29#Inverse_image), we have $$x\in f^{-1}(A \cap B)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in A\cap B$$
$$\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in A\mbox{ and }f(x)\in B$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(A)\mbox{ and }x\in f^{-1}(B)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B).$$

Therefore, we have $f^{-1}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: Amusingly, this is precisely the specialisation of the usual proof that right adjoints preserve limits in category theory...

Comment: @ZhenLin: Interesting observation!

Comment: This proof has problem, for it would also be true if $f^{-1}$ is replaced by $f$. However $f(A\cap B) \subset f(A) \cap f(B)$, and not $f(A\cap B=f(A) \cap f(B)$

Comment: @hermes Why do you say that?

Comment: As I explained in the example, this proof also works for $f$. However, actually we do not have $f(A∩B)=f(A)∩f(B)$, but only $f(A∩B)\subset f(A)∩f(B)$.

Comment: To be more precise, it needs $f(f^{−1}(A∩B))\subset A\cap B$. So second line becomes $f(x)\in f(f^{−1}(A∩B))\subset A\cap B$. Since $f^{−1}(f(A∩B)))\supset A\cap B$, it is not true for $f$.

Comment: @hermes the proof does not work for f. The point is f(x) has a single value (f inverse does not)