# Image of Intersection of sects not equal to intersection of images of sets

Tags: functions

How to disprove, if $f$ is a function,  $f(A \cap B) != f(A) \cap f(B)?$

Answer (score 12):

Counterexample: Let $f\colon\{1,2\}\rightarrow\{1\}$ be given by $f(1)=1,f(2)=1$ and let $A=\{1\},B=\{2\}$.

To see why this is a counter example, note that $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and so $f(A\cap B)=\emptyset$, but $f(A)\cap f(B)=\{1\}\cap\{1\}=\{1\}$ and so the LHS is not equal to the RHS.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!!! But I was looking for an answer along the lines of
 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105956/proof-of-intersection-of-inverse-images-of-functions . I mean I do get it from examples, but I am unable to understand it in mathematical terms. At which step, does this equation fall?

Comment: @user1063185 It's not an equation because equality does not hold, so it's not a well-posed question to ask when it fails. Note that this is more than 'an example'. It is precisely a proof that not for all $A$ and $B$ does $f(A\cap B)= f(A)\cap f(B)$.

Comment: Are there any "pretty" functions that anyone knows that can be used as a suitable counter example as well?

Comment: @Valentino How about $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \colon x \mapsto x^2$ with $A = (-\infty,0)$ and $B = (0,\infty)$. Then $f(A \cap B) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ but $f(A) \cap f(B) = (0,\infty) \cap (0,\infty) = (0,\infty)$.